error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect
I am getting the above error when I try to build images using Azure Pipelines. I have scoured the net and tried few solutions, but nothing seems to work. Any help?
I tried the below commands as suggested by others, but to no avail.
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker" ./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon

From the error message, the account used to run the Pipeline Agent has no enough permission to use docker. You can refer to the answer to change the account used to run the agent. If it not work,  you  can share more detailed information about the error(Azure Pipeline definition and Pipeline error log).


In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect

From the error message, the account used to run the Pipeline Agent has no enough permission to use docker.
When you use the Microsoft-hosted agent, the Pipeline agent will use the admin account(Account name: VssAdministrator)to run the agent by default. It should have enough access to build docker image.
If you are using Self-hosted Agent, you can change to use Administrator account to run the Self-hosted Agent.
Here are the steps:
For interactive mode self-hosted agent:
You could use the following command to create an agent with admin account.
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --pool default --agent myAgent --runAsAutoLogon --windowsLogonAccount myDomain\adminaccount --windowsLogonPassword Password

For service mode self-hosted agent:
You could create an agent with the admin account(similar as interactive mode).
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --pool default --agent myAgent --runAsService --windowsLogonAccount myDomain\adminccount --windowsLogonPassword Password

To modify the existing service mode self-hosted agent, you could navigate to local system -> Services and find the running agent service.
Then you could change the logon account as admin account.


Where is this local system ->Service?

@VarunSenthil You can search the Services  in the windows system search bar

This is from a client account, so I guess they'll have to sort it out then

@VarunSenthil Yes. If the current account has no enough permission, you need to change to use another account which has enough permission to use docker on machine.

Yes, I got an update just a few hours ago. The issue was as you mentioned. The user triggering the pipeline needed elevated privileges. Works fine now.

@VarunSenthil Glad to know that it can work fine now.
